# Power set including a null value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If I need to find  $\mathcal{P}(X)$ if 
  $ X = \{ \emptyset, \{\alpha, \beta, \gamma \}, \gamma, \{\{ \alpha, \beta \} \} \}$, would the cardinality be $2^4$ taking into account the null value? Would the answer be the exact same as if I substituted the original $4$ values as $\{a, b, c, d \}$ and then found the power set of it?

Comment: Yes; the power set of a set $X$ with 4 elements will have $2^4$ elements, i.e. all the subsets of $X$.

Comment: You must be careful with $\emptyset$, which is subset of every set, and $\{ \emptyset \}$, the one-element set that **in this specific case** is a subset of $X$.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is not a "null value". It is a set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set $X$ with four things $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ and another set $Y$ with another for things $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$, the the power sets $\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mathcal P(Y)$ will have the same number of elements ($2^4$) because if $\psi$ is a bijection between $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\}$, then $\psi$ induces a bijection between $\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mathcal P(Y)$, defined by $A\mapsto\psi(A)$.

In particualr, yes, $\mathcal P\bigl(\{\emptyset,\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\},\gamma,\{\{\alpha,\beta\}\}\}\bigr)$ has as many elements as $\mathcal P\bigl(\{a,b,c,d\}\bigr)$,